# Finding the $S$ matrix for algebraic Riccati equation from data?

Tags: matlab, covariance

Assume that you have two vectors. The gaussian white noise with zero mean $e \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times N}$ and the white disturbance zero mean vector $\omega \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times N}$

If I create this matrix

$$A = \frac{1}{N}\begin{bmatrix}
\omega \omega^T & \omega e^T \\ 
e\omega^T & ee^T 
\end{bmatrix}$$

And then I take the $Q = A(1:n, 1:n)$ I get the same results as if I compute the MATLAB commando

```
Q = cov(w')
```

Same if I compute $R = A(n+1:n+p, n+1:n+p)$

```
R = cov(e')
```

But what if I want to find the $S$ matrix for the Algebratic Riccati Equation? The simple solution is $S = A(1:n, n+1:n+p)$.

**Question:**

Is there any way I could use MATLAB commando `cov` for computing $S$ if I know $e$ and $\omega$?

**How to reproduce this issue:**

1. Install MATLAB or GNU Octave
2. Download [MataveID](http://www.github.com/danielmartensson/mataveid) and [Matavecontrol](http://www.github.com/danielmartensson/matavecontrol) and install it, or just stand in the same folder as the `.m` files together. Installation instructions are available at the page.
3. open `cca.m` file

Then change these lines

```
% Computing the covariance matrix
covariance = [w*w' w*e'; e*w' e*e']/(N-2); % <<-- Change this to 2 instead of 1

% Compute Q, R, S for the riccati equation
Q = covariance(1:n, 1:n) % No semicolon
R = covariance(n+1:n+p, n+1:n+p) % No semicolon
S = covariance(1:n, n+1:n+p) % No semicolon

% Add these
Q1 = cov(w')
R1 = cov(e')
%S1 = cov ?
```

4. 

Run these in the command window.

```
G = tf(1, [1 1.5 1]);
[u, t] = gensig('square', 10, 10, 100);
u = [u*5 u*2 -u 10*u -2*u];
t = linspace(0, 50, length(u));
y = lsim(G, u, t);
close
yn = y + randn(1, length(y)); % Random noise.
sysd = cca(u, yn, 50, t(2), 0, 2);
```

You are going to see this output

```
Q =

   3.8349e-09   2.2685e-08
   2.2685e-08   1.8307e-07

R = 1.0207
S =

  -5.0560e-05
  -2.4577e-04

Q1 =

   3.8348e-09   2.2685e-08
   2.2685e-08   1.8307e-07

R1 = 1.0207
>>
```

As you can see, `Q = Q1` and `R = R1`, but how about `S = S1` ? How can I use `cov` to reproduce `S1` that is going to exactly as `S` ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141905/discussion-on-question-by-euraad-finding-the-s-matrix-for-algebratic-riccati-e).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was not what I was expecting. I just wanted to use `cov` command from MATLAB to find `Q, R, S` matrices for the Algebraic Riccati Equation from measurement data. The solution given by KBS in their first comment is very simple and simply consists of doing

```
covariance = cov([w' e']); % Old way = [w*w' w*e'; e*w' e*e']/(N-1);

% Compute Q, R, S for the Riccati equation
Q = covariance(1:n, 1:n);
R = covariance(n+1:n+p, n+1:n+p);
S = covariance(1:n, n+1:n+p);
```

Comment: That's exactly the solution I gave you. You have not found anything.